# Create a bitmap image from HEX codes in CSV

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jpeg, bmp

I have a program set up in my google sheet to generate images based on conditions by assigning each cell with a hex color code. When each hex code is converted into the color it represents, the result is an image. I'm wondering how to take these hex code values, export them as a csv, then turn that csv into a bmp image that can be saved as a jpeg. Since a bitmap image is nothing more than an array of values (color values) just like a csv is an array of data, it seems like this should be simple??? For example, I have a csv pasted below that when converted to a bitmap image should be a 9 px wide by 7 px wide image that says HI in black pixels.

```
#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF
#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#000000,#000000,#000000,#FFFFFF
#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF
#FFFFFF,#000000,#000000,#000000,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF
#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF
#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#000000,#FFFFFF,#000000,#000000,#000000,#FFFFFF
#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, it seems that you are using Google Spreadsheet. From this situation, how about converting the pixel color data to an image using Canvas API of Javascript? When this API is used, your goal can be achieved. But, in the current stage, it seems that Canvas API cannot directly export the image as BMP. So, in this answer, from `then turn that csv into a bmp image that can be saved as a jpeg.`, the image is exported as a Jpeg image.

### Sample script:

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet as the script file. In this script, it supposes that your HEX data in your question is put in a sheet of Google Spreadsheet. So, the HEX data is directly retrieved from Spreadsheet and exported as a JPEG file. Before you use this script, please set the sheet name.

```js
const getData = _ => ({
  filename: "sampleFilename.jpg",
  data: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues()
});

// Please run this function.
const openDialog = _ => SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "sample");
```

#### HTML & Javascript: `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet as the HTML file.

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(({filename, data}) => {
  const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const context = c.getContext("2d");
  context.canvas.width = data[0].length;
  context.canvas.height = data.length;
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      context.fillStyle = c;
      context.fillRect(j, i, 1, 1);
    })
  })
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  a.click();
  google.script.host.close();
}).getData();
</script>
```

- When you run the function `openDialog` at the script editor, a dialog is opened on Google Spreadsheet. And HTML and Javascript are run on the dialog. Then, the JPEG file converted from the HEX data is downloaded.

#### Note:

- If the CSV file is put in your Google Drive, you can also retrieve the HEX data from the following script. In this case, please replace the above `getData` to the following script.

  ```
    const getData = _ => {
      const fileId = "###"; // File ID of the CSV file in your Google Drive.
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
      const csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      const filename = file.getName().replace(".csv", ".jpg");
      const data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
      return {filename, data};
    }
  ```
- When you want to create the converted JPEG file to Google Drive, please create it with `c.toDataURL("image/jpeg")` at Google Apps Script side.
- When this script is run using your sample values, the following image is exported.

  [image]

#### Reference:

- [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)